# How to share images between IIS websites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have 2 websites sitting on an IIS server in different app pool and locations:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\QC
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PublicQC
```

Where QC is a local website for use inside the network. In here we have a `Images` folder, which loads images to display with the path

```
~/Images
```

And this works fine. However, I need to also display these images on the public site. How can I access the images in a different app pool for display?

I tried setting the path to

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\QC\Images
```

But this gives a

> not allowed to load local resource

For each image.

I thought maybe something like this would work, but then no images are retrieved

```
~/~/QC/Images
```

or

```
~/../QC/Images
```

I also tried setting it using absolute path as per the comments

```
http://localhost:PORT/Images
//localhost:PORT/Images
localhost:PORT/Images
```

But I get

> 'http:/localhost:3000/Images/9478/1/1/' is not a valid virtual path

How can I access these images from my `PublicQC` site, preferably using a relative path?

Comment: You can use the absolute url to the other site which has the images

Comment: @Shyju Thanks for your comment I set the path to `http://localhost:PORT/Images`, but now I'm getting a 500 internal error. I can confirm that I am able to navigate to the images themselves by going to `http://localhost:PORT/Images/image.jpg` in my browser

Comment: If the url `yourSiteBaseName/QC/Images/imgage.jpg`, works , you can use that as the img src for the other site.

Comment: You can also have an action method which reads the image from the network path and return the image and use the url to that action method as your image url.

Comment: @Shyju when using the absolute URL I am now getting `http:/localhost:3000/Images/9478/1/1/' is not a valid virtual path` Do you happen to know what this means? I am able to change the src in web inspector and it works fine (Also notice the missing `/` in the error... it seems to have broken my url)

Comment: To start with ,you should be able to render the image using that url in a browser. Does `http:/localhost:3000/Images/9478/1/1/` in the browser rendering an image ?If not , fix the url and then use that url

Comment: @Shyju The url to the image works on its own, but after saving the absolute path into my web.config, I see the error about virtual path, and notice that `http://` is missing a `/`, so obviously THAT url doesn't work because it is not properly formed, however I don't know at what stage the url is being changed

Comment: @Shyju Ok I think I got it working, as I can now see the images when I navigate from the server. However, it I try to access `PublicSite` from outside the network, the images fail to load again and just display the alt text. I guess this is because the images are actually hosted on a site which is not on an open port (QC)... how annoying